# What switches can robocopy use to preserve file and directory times on the target?

Tags: robocopy, timestamp

After using robocopy to copy files to a new drive I realized that all the file and directory creation times and been reset to the time of copying.

Are there some switches to make robocopy keep the original files times?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take a look at the options for the `/COPY:[copyflags]` and `/DCOPY` switches.

As per the `ROBOCOPY /?` usage info:

```
/COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
                      (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps).
                      (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

/DCOPY:T :: COPY Directory Timestamps.
```

For example:

```
ROBOCOPY c:\src d:\dest /MIR /COPY:DT /DCOPY:T
```

Will copy all files and folders and preserve the date and time stamps.

```
ROBOCOPY c:\src d:\dest /MIR /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T
```

Will copy all files and folders and preserve the date & time stamps and file attributes.

There is also another (and I believe deprecated?) switch `/TIMFIX` which does much the same as `/COPY:DT` but it doesn't fix the time stamps on folders.

These were tested with ROBOCOPY 5.1.10.1027 on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Be aware that the `/MIR` switch mirrors the directory that you are copying from; that is, `/MIR` will also delete files in the destination folder not found in the source folder. The `/MIR` switch is the equivalent of `/E` and the `/PURGE` switches used together (but with a [minor exception](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_remarks)).

Comment: How do you see your Robo version?

Comment: @Pacerier `Right-click -> Properties -> Details tab` on the executable which is normally located at `C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe`

Comment: Not possible I'm on UEFI cmd `X:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe`. Is there a cmd way to do it?

Comment: @Pacerier - I don't know what you mean by "Not possible I'm on UEFI", can you explain?

Comment: @Pacerier one of these methods might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version

Comment: It means my laptop is currently "UEFI booted". I've got no UI here, just a cmd prompt.

Comment: @Pacerier try asking on superuser.com. I don't have any more time today.

Comment: Beware of `/MOVE` flag, because it anyway changes a directory modification time.

Answer (score 3):

I use this at work.  Safer than using the /MIR switch which can overwrite or delete data.  This will copy timestamps for folders and files.

```
robocopy G:\users\username F:\Users\username /COPYALL /E /dcopy:T /SECFIX
```

/E copies empty folders (remove if not needed)

/SECFIX copies the NTFS permissions (remove if not needed)

/XO can be added to exclude older (ie if doing a true-up for a folder migration)